# Initialize an NSArray with the numbers in a sequential manner when the count of the array is known

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

I want to initialize an `NSArray` with numbers starting from `0,1,2,3...` I know the count of the array. For example:

I have an array that needs to be initialized with `5` (count) as capacity. Now I  want to initialize this array with `0,1,2,3,4` and I need to initialize it dynamically.

If the count of the array is `10`, I need to initialize the array with `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` at respective indexes. The problem is that count of the array changes dynamically and I need to initialize it accordingly.

Can someone suggest me any idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray* arrOfObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i< [arr count]; i++)
{
    arrOfObject addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize a mutable array. Then add the numbers in a loop. Optionally initialize a new non-mutable array with your mutable one using `arrayWithArray:`.

Comment: I've not included a complete snippet on purpose, so he could learn how to do such basic things by himself. Now there are 3 copy-paste solutions hoping to get some reputation...

Answer (score 1):

```
 int count = 5;//suppose this you want
 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
 for(int i=0 ; i< count; i++) {
     [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
 }
```

You just need to pass the count from where you want it, and it will dynamically generate your desired array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSMutableArray` then just add as many as you need

```
int count = 10;

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```